# AngularJS Directive - Template replacements inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following directive code (AngularJS 1.4.8).  The issue I have is using template replacements inside the ng-repeat.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').directive('formGroup', formGroup);

    var template = '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<label class="control-label">{{label}}</label>' +
        '<div data-ng-transclude></div>' +
        '<span class="text-danger field-validation-error" data-ng-repeat="errorMessage in {{form}}.$error.{{model}}.messages">' +
        '{{errorMessage}}' +
        '</span>' +
        '</div>';

    function formGroup () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: '^form',
            transclude: true,
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                label: '@',
                model: '@'
            },
            template: template,
            link: link
        };
    }

    function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.form = element.closest('form').attr('name');
    }
})();
```

It is used in HTML in the following way (server-validate is another directive that puts in-line validation errors returned from the server into the ng-repeat in the directive).

```
<form name="myForm" data-ng-submit="submit()">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div data-form-group data-label="Memeber number" data-model="memberNumber">
            <input type="text"
                   class="form-control"
                   data-ng-model="model.memberNumber"
                   data-server-validate />
        </div>
</form>
```

I want it to produce the following output HTML.

```
<form name="myForm" data-ng-submit="submit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Member number</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text"
                   class="form-control"
                   data-ng-model="model.memberNumber"
                   data-server-validate" />
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-error"
                  data-ng-repeat="errorMessage in myForm.$error.memberNumber.messages">
                {{errorMessage}}
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

However, it gets the following error.

```
[Error] [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{form}}.$error.{{model}}.messages] starting at [{form}}.$error.{{model}}.messages]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since form controller is injected as required, using the formcontroller, the error messages can be handled like below.

```
function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {            
        var unbinder = scope.$watch(function () {return ctrl[scope.model] }, function(value) {
            if (!value) return;
            scope.errorMessagesList = ctrl[scope.model].$error;
            unbinder();
        })
    }
```

The complete working sample is availabe in the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/acb3c8n7/5/

Answer (score 0):

In the link function use:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    scope.formString = element.closest('form').attr('name');
    scope.form = scope.$eval(scope.formString);
}
```

In the template use:

```
ng-repeat="errorMessage in form.$error[model].messages"
```

The `$eval` method evaluates the string as an Angular expression and will return a reference to the `myForm` object.

Answer (score 0):

`closest()` is not present in the `element`argument (check [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)).

Also you have several errors, by example you don't provide a `name` attribute in the input, this causes that the scope.myForm object don't recognize the `model` string provided how a property.

```
<input type="text" name="memberNumber"
                   class="form-control"
                   data-ng-model="model.memberNumber"
                   data-server-validate" />
```

In your `ng-repeat` you shouldn't provide a expression like this:

> {{form}}.$error.{{model}}.messages

you should be create a property to attach the form object and the use some like this --> http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/eZGZPX